# AWS CDK / NodejsFunction: beforeInstall, beforeBundling, afterBundling

Tags: node.js, docker, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, amazon-linux

I'm working on a project with an AWS Infrastructure. I work with `aws-cdk-lib` for IaC to simplify the whole process.

The flow is the following:

1. User upload photo/video to S3 Bucket
2. A lambda is triggered to compress the file with `sharp` and store it on another S3 Bucket with a short TTL.
3. A S3 Notification event trigger another lambda which will upload the S3Object to a Storj Bucket.

So, I need to use `uplink-nodejs` library to store images and videos on the Storj DCS service.

The issue is that, in order to install `uplink-nodejs` i need to install `make` command and copy `./node_modules/uplink-nodejs/* /` for uplink command to be available to the system.

But I can't find a way to install all required dependancies and make the required commands.

I've already tried multiple solutions:

1. Use `NodejsFunction` bundling options (beforeInstall, beforeBundling, afterBundling).
2. Create a `.dockerfile` in my lambda folder.

The first solution throw an error for `su` command and `sudo` command, which prevent me from installing `make`

The second solution doesn't seems specifically relevant in my situation.

Someone have an idea of what's happening ?

Here's the AWS CDK NestedStack for the ContentService with the lambdas:

```
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import * as lambda from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda';
import * as dynamodb from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-dynamodb';
import * as s3 from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-s3';

import * as path from 'path';

import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import { NodejsFunction } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda-nodejs';
import { DockerImage } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { LambdaDestination } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-s3-notifications';

interface ContentServiceProps extends cdk.NestedStackProps {
    main_table: dynamodb.Table;
    user_content_bucket: s3.Bucket;
};

export class ContentService extends cdk.NestedStack {

    public readonly content_service_handler: NodejsFunction;
    public readonly storj_image_lambda: NodejsFunction;

    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: ContentServiceProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        this.storj_image_lambda = new NodejsFunction(this, "storj_image_lambda", {
            entry: path.join(__dirname, '../../lambda-fns/src/functions/storj_upload/index.ts'),
            bundling: {
                nodeModules: ["uplink-nodejs", "node-gyp"],
                forceDockerBundling: true,
                commandHooks: {
                    beforeInstall(_inputDir, outputDir) {
                        return [
                            'export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin',
                            'sudo yum -y install make'
                        ]
                    },
                    beforeBundling(inputDir, outputDir) {
                        return [
                            ''
                        ]
                    },
                    afterBundling(inputDir, outputDir) {
                        return [`cp -r ./node_modules/uplink-nodejs /usr`]
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        this.content_service_handler = new NodejsFunction(this, "content_service_handler", {
            runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_16_X,
            handler: 'handler',
            entry: path.join(__dirname, "../../lambda-fns/src/functions/content/index.ts"),
            environment: {
                TABLE_NAME: props.main_table.tableName,
                USER_CONTENT: props.user_content_bucket.bucketName,
                STORJ_LAMBDA: this.storj_image_lambda.functionName
            }
        });



        props.main_table.grantFullAccess(this.content_service_handler);
        props.user_content_bucket.grantRead(this.content_service_handler);
        props.user_content_bucket.addEventNotification(s3.EventType.OBJECT_CREATED, new LambdaDestination(this.storj_image_lambda));
    };
};
```

And here's the logs I get when I try to deploy the my Stack:

```
Bundling asset MainStack/content_service/storj_image_lambda/Code/Stage...

  asset-output/index.js  1.5kb

⚡ Done in 21ms
bash: sudo: command not found
/Users/thomgeenen/Git/nude_safer_cdk/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/asset-staging.js:2
`),localBundling=options.local?.tryBundle(bundleDir,options),!localBundling){let user;if(options.user)user=options.user;else{const userInfo=os.userInfo();user=userInfo.uid!==-1?`${userInfo.uid}:${userInfo.gid}`:"1000:1000"}options.image.run({command:options.command,user,volumes,environment:options.environment,entrypoint:options.entrypoint,workingDirectory:options.workingDirectory??AssetStaging.BUNDLING_INPUT_DIR,securityOpt:options.securityOpt??""})}}catch(err){const bundleErrorDir=bundleDir+"-error";throw fs.existsSync(bundleErrorDir)&&fs.removeSync(bundleErrorDir),fs.renameSync(bundleDir,bundleErrorDir),new Error(`Failed to bundle asset ${this.node.path}, bundle output is located at ${bundleErrorDir}: ${err}`)}if(fs_1.FileSystem.isEmpty(bundleDir)){const outputDir=localBundling?bundleDir:AssetStaging.BUNDLING_OUTPUT_DIR;throw new Error(`Bundling did not produce any output. Check that content is written to ${outputDir}.`)}}calculateHash(hashType,bundling,outputDir){if(hashType==assets_1.AssetHashType.CUSTOM||hashType==assets_1.AssetHashType.SOURCE&&bundling){const hash=crypto.createHash("sha256");return hash.update(this.customSourceFingerprint??fs_1.FileSystem.fingerprint(this.sourcePath,this.fingerprintOptions)),bundling&&hash.update(JSON.stringify(bundling)),hash.digest("hex")}switch(hashType){case assets_1.AssetHashType.SOURCE:return fs_1.FileSystem.fingerprint(this.sourcePath,this.fingerprintOptions);case assets_1.AssetHashType.BUNDLE:case assets_1.AssetHashType.OUTPUT:if(!outputDir)throw new Error(`Cannot use \`${hashType}\` hash type when \`bundling\` is not specified.`);return fs_1.FileSystem.fingerprint(outputDir,this.fingerprintOptions);default:throw new Error("Unknown asset hash type.")}}}exports.AssetStaging=AssetStaging,_a=JSII_RTTI_SYMBOL_1,AssetStaging[_a]={fqn:"aws-cdk-lib.AssetStaging",version:"2.53.0"},AssetStaging.BUNDLING_INPUT_DIR="/asset-input",AssetStaging.BUNDLING_OUTPUT_DIR="/asset-output",AssetStaging.assetCache=new cache_1.Cache;function renderAssetFilename(assetHash,extension=""){return`asset.${assetHash}${extension}`}function determineHashType(assetHashType,customSourceFingerprint){const hashType=customSourceFingerprint?assetHashType??assets_1.AssetHashType.CUSTOM:assetHashType??assets_1.AssetHashType.SOURCE;if(customSourceFingerprint&&hashType!==assets_1.AssetHashType.CUSTOM)throw new Error(`Cannot specify \`${assetHashType}\` for \`assetHashType\` when \`assetHash\` is specified. Use \`CUSTOM\` or leave \`undefined\`.`);if(hashType===assets_1.AssetHashType.CUSTOM&&!customSourceFingerprint)throw new Error("`assetHash` must be specified when `assetHashType` is set to `AssetHashType.CUSTOM`.");return hashType}function calculateCacheKey(props){return crypto.createHash("sha256").update(JSON.stringify(sortObject(props))).digest("hex")}function sortObject(object){if(typeof object!="object"||object instanceof Array)return object;const ret={};for(const key of Object.keys(object).sort())ret[key]=sortObject(object[key]);return ret}function singleArchiveFile(directory){if(!fs.existsSync(directory))throw new Error(`Directory ${directory} does not exist.`);if(!fs.statSync(directory).isDirectory())throw new Error(`${directory} is not a directory.`);const content=fs.readdirSync(directory);if(content.length===1){const file=path.join(directory,content[0]),extension=getExtension(content[0]).toLowerCase();if(fs.statSync(file).isFile()&&ARCHIVE_EXTENSIONS.includes(extension))return file}}function determineBundledAsset(bundleDir,outputType){const archiveFile=singleArchiveFile(bundleDir);switch(outputType===bundling_1.BundlingOutput.AUTO_DISCOVER&&(outputType=archiveFile?bundling_1.BundlingOutput.ARCHIVED:bundling_1.BundlingOutput.NOT_ARCHIVED),outputType){case bundling_1.BundlingOutput.NOT_ARCHIVED:return{path:bundleDir,packaging:assets_1.FileAssetPackaging.ZIP_DIRECTORY};case bundling_1.BundlingOutput.ARCHIVED:if(!archiveFile)throw new Error("Bundling output directory is expected to include only a single archive file when `output` is set to `ARCHIVED`");return{path:archiveFile,packaging:assets_1.FileAssetPackaging.FILE,extension:getExtension(archiveFile)}}}function getExtension(source){for(const ext of ARCHIVE_EXTENSIONS)if(source.toLowerCase().endsWith(ext))return ext;return path.extname(source)}
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ^
Error: Failed to bundle asset MainStack/content_service/storj_image_lambda/Code/Stage, bundle output is located at /Users/thomgeenen/Git/nude_safer_cdk/cdk.out/bundling-temp-4e95a752d2aca74dd84aa402102b31591eb7ee9ec0a94b306360353a61e924f0-error: Error: docker exited with status 127
    at AssetStaging.bundle (/Users/thomgeenen/Git/nude_safer_cdk/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/asset-staging.js:2:614)
    at AssetStaging.stageByBundling (/Users/thomgeenen/Git/nude_safer_cdk/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/asset-staging.js:1:4506)
    at stageThisAsset (/Users/thomgeenen/Git/nude_safer_cdk/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/asset-staging.js:1:1867)
    at Cache.obtain (/Users/thomgeenen/Git/nude_safer_cdk/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/private/cache.js:1:242)
    at new AssetStaging (/Users/thomgeenen/Git/nude_safer_cdk/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/asset-staging.js:1:2262)
    at new Asset (/Users/thomgeenen/Git/nude_safer_cdk/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-s3-assets/lib/asset.js:1:736)
    at AssetCode.bind (/Users/thomgeenen/Git/nude_safer_cdk/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda/lib/code.js:1:4628)
    at new Function (/Users/thomgeenen/Git/nude_safer_cdk/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda/lib/function.js:1:2803)
    at new NodejsFunction (/Users/thomgeenen/Git/nude_safer_cdk/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda-nodejs/lib/function.js:1:1171)
    at new ContentService (/Users/thomgeenen/Git/nude_safer_cdk/lib/services/content/index.ts:24:35)
Detected file changes during deployment. Invoking 'cdk deploy' again
[+] Building 0.5s (13/13) FINISHED                                                                                                                  
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 37B                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for public.ecr.aws/sam/build-nodejs14.x:latest                                                                    0.4s
 => [1/9] FROM public.ecr.aws/sam/build-nodejs14.x@sha256:cfe32c14b97a6d5d7128f4e110c6d11b80bf89c0cca8a3493879f8c587627655                     0.0s
 => CACHED [2/9] RUN npm install --global yarn@1.22.5                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [3/9] RUN npm install --global pnpm                                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [4/9] RUN npm install --global typescript                                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [5/9] RUN npm install --global --unsafe-perm=true esbuild@0                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [6/9] RUN mkdir /tmp/npm-cache &&     chmod -R 777 /tmp/npm-cache &&     npm config --global set cache /tmp/npm-cache               0.0s
 => CACHED [7/9] RUN mkdir /tmp/yarn-cache &&     chmod -R 777 /tmp/yarn-cache &&     yarn config set cache-folder /tmp/yarn-cache             0.0s
 => CACHED [8/9] RUN npm config --global set update-notifier false                                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [9/9] RUN /sbin/useradd -u 1000 user && chmod 711 /                                                                                 0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:c83389551577052395325ed8a0fb51c59639344b8c92baa1656956f23c765d18                                                   0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/cdk-7ef608663d730a301f1ab98604e57fd96273751c63db25a1a75f1390f462c655                                        0.0s

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
```